# What are some organic-approved solvents I can use to make my own liquid agri-mixes?

Tags: pesticide

I have a few ideas for organic pesticides/fungicides etc. They're intended to be sprayable, and ideally soluble in water.

What are some organic-approved solvents?

Comment: Water? That's a solvent and I'd assume it's organic-approved.

Comment: Water doesn't dissolve or form homogenous mixtures and emulsions with a lot of the stuff that's commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you may not get many answers here because it’s illegal to dispense advice about pesticides if one isn’t licensed.  If one is licensed, there are lots of caveats that answering a generic question on a website violate.  Additives to pesticides are considered legally as pesticides.

You could Google “omri approved adjuvants.”  OMRI is the Organic Materials Review Institute, and is a major certifier of organic practices in the US.

A real answer would depend, as the comments imply, on what you are trying to dissolve, what you are using as a dilutant, etc.  But I wouldn’t risk the license I no longer maintain in order to answer without seeing your site, etc.!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not making products for sale, this is for my own use at my own organic farm. Also, wasn't aware that it is illegal to give advice about this online, perhaps it's the same in my country, too. :)